# Type error: dayofweek() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'days' and 'yr'

Tags: python

I was working on my python practice session and ran into a typo problem.
It was about Doomsday algorithm.

Error code:

> Type error: dayofweek() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'days' and 'yr'

```
weekdays = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
def dayofweek(month, day, yr):
    Anchor = (16 - 2 * (yr // 100 % 4)) % 7
    yr = yr % 100
    yrs_12 = yr % 12
    offset = yr // 12 + yrs_12 + yrs_12 // 4 + centuryAnchor
    monpos = [0, 3, 0, 7, 4, 9, 6, 11, 8, 12, 10, 14, 12][month]
print(dayofweek(*map(int, input().split())))
```

Comment: Are you sure you entered all the `input` in `one` line ? I think, you entered it in multiple lines ?

Comment: @niekas The error says, `missing 2 required positional arguments`. So looks like he just did `<enter>` after the first input

Comment: so what is the correct to put this code into work?

Comment: Where does `centuryAnchor` comes from and what is the `Anchor` for ? Is that the full code ?

Answer (score 0):

You have probably provided a wrong input for your `input()` function. For example, instead of input '11 12 2019' you have inputted something like '11/12/2019'. Otherwise your code works fine.

Try replacing `input()` with `"11 12 2019"` and it will work just fine.

Comment: This program should ask for input of ancher and year, so I did something wrong here